# How to log custom object using ILogger in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net, logging, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-logging

Some loggers are able to log custom object, e.g. in custom dimensions in application insights:

[image]

How do I add custom object to custom dimensions using `ILogger`?

I think I've previously used anonymous class for this:

```
Logger.LogInformation("Some Message {Parameter1} {Parameter2}", new 
{ 
    Parameter1 = "foo", //PropertyName must match message format
    Parameter2 = "foo", //PropertyName must match message format
    CustomData = customData
});
```

but the SimpleConsoleLogger is not working and causing an error:

> System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Comment: You have a link to the specific type you are using (SimpleConsoleLogger)?

Comment: I have default asp.net 6 web app template + application insights. No additional dependencies. I think SimpleConsoleLogger is default in asp.net core, built-in type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#simple

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be related with that Logger methods expects to get array of parameters `params`. You are passing object here.

Logger structured logs are not really matching your placeholders based on the name but actual order (in an array).

So instead on your usage you should really use and array as a parameter or pass your variables directly as `params`

```
Logger.LogInformation("Some Message {Parameter1} {Parameter2} {lastOne}", new object[]
{ 
    "foo",
    "foo",
    customData
});

// Or

Logger.LogInformation("Some Message {Parameter1} {Parameter2} {lastOne}", "foo", "foo", customData);
```

So the exception you are seeing is really saying that your string has 2 placeholders `Parameter1` and `Parameter2`, but you provided just one object to `LogInformation` method, currently it cannot assign anything to your `Parameter2`.

Comment: Logger expects either a array of parameter or an object, whose properties should matches the parameters in format string

Comment: @Liero in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.loggerextensions.loginformation?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0 could you show me which override are you talking about? I cannot find any evidence of what you are saying in microsoft docs